# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'fechaNacimiento' - laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have an error executing migrations

[image]

migrations:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class MakeSomeColumnsNullableToPacientesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('pacientes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('obra_social_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->change();
            $table->integer('plan_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->change();

            $table->integer('pais_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->change();
            $table->integer('provincia_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->change();
            $table->integer('localidad_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->change();

            $table->date('fechaNacimiento')->nullable()->change();
            $table->string('telefono', 25)->nullable()->change();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('pacientes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('obra_social_id')->unsigned()->change();
            $table->integer('plan_id')->unsigned()->change();
        });
    }
}
```

**help pls**
**it does not allow me to execute migrations well thanks to this error**

fechaNacimiento == **birth date**

table original: $table->date('fechaNacimiento');

Comment: Are you sure the provided migration corresponds to the query executed? `fechaNacimiento` was not given a default value but the query does try to set one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try set default value for you column:

```
$table->date('fechaNacimiento')->nullable()->default(NULL)->change();
```

or:

```
 $table->date('fechaNacimiento')->nullable()->default('DEFAULT')->change();
```